# Python console output gets overwritten in Debian 6

Tags: python, linux, debian

I have a small script in python which automates installation of a few packages like wget, git, using apt-get in Debian 6 (Python 2.6.6). the script then installs `pip` and then using `pip`, installs *requests* and *phpserialize*. The following is the output got when the script is run:

```
root@ffVMdeb64:~# python test.py 
Reading package lists... Done
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/src/forpip': File exists
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
wget is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%


Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): phpserialize in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
git is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

At the end, there the script takes some input from the user. However, the `raw_input` statement gets executed while the output for the install process is still going on and hence gets overwritten. Notice the blank space between 2 blocks of output above - that is where the `raw_input` statement gets printed and then overwritten.

The relevant parts of the script is as follows:

```
subprocess.call("pip install phpserialize &> /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install requests &> /dev/null  2>&1", shell=True)
subprocess.call("apt-get install git -y &> /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
import phpserialize
import requests
from phpserialize import serialize
from phpserialize import unserialize

def checktext():
    text = raw_input("\n\n\nEnter your text:")
    return text

itext = checktext()
```

I tested the exact same script in CentOS 6.3 and 6.4 and it worked as expected. I guess it has something to do with the `Building dependency tree... 50%` part of `apt-get` but i am not sure.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the exact solution and I'm pretty sure there'll be a better solution but i think if you try `sleep` after your last `apt-get` statement, it might work.

As per your code:

```
import time
subprocess.call("pip install phpserialize &> /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install requests &> /dev/null  2>&1", shell=True)
subprocess.call("apt-get install git -y &> /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
import phpserialize
import requests
from phpserialize import serialize
from phpserialize import unserialize

def checktext():
    text = raw_input("\n\n\nEnter your text:")
    return text

itext = checktext()
```

That causes the whole `apt-get` to execute first and then moves on to your `text=...` statment.

Hope this helps